Russian roulette with a six-shot revolver

Consider that there are $6$ ordered players such that the $1^{\rm st}$ one takes the revolver  loads $1$ of the $6$ chambers with a real bullet and the other $5$ chambers with fake bullets and spins the cylinder and shoots himself, supposing that the bullet fired is chosen randomly. If he survives, then the $2^{\rm nd}$ one reloads the cylinder with $2$ real bullets and $4$ fake bullets and so on. If one player dies, the game ends.

Let $F, S,T$ be the events of the $1^{\rm st}; 2^{\rm nd}; 3^{\rm rd}$ players surviving respectively.
Now the probability of the $1^{\rm st}$ one surviving is simply $\frac{5}{6} \;(P(F)=\frac{5}{6})$ and for the $2^{\rm nd}$ one surviving, we have:
$$P(S)=P(S|F)P(F)+P(S|\overline{F})P(\overline{F})=\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{5}{6}+1\times\frac{1}{6}=\frac{13}{18}$$
And for the third one:
$$P(T)=P(T|S)P(S)+P(T|\overline{S})P(\overline{S})=\frac{2}{3} \times\frac{13}{18}+1 \times\frac{5}{18}=\frac{41}{54}$$
But I have feeling that the value that I calculated for $P(T)$ is not correct; any ideas?
EDIT: Writing $P(T)=P(T|F)P(F)+P(T|\overline{F})P(\overline{F})$ leads to the result  $\frac{13}{18}$

The third player dies if and only if the first two players don't die (for everyone else survives when one dies) and the third player fires a real bullet. The probability of this happening is
$$\frac56×\frac46×\frac36=\frac5{18}$$
where the numerators refer to there being 5 blanks, 4 blanks and 3 real bullets respectively for the first, second and third players. The complement is the probability you are looking for and is $\frac{13}{18}$.
This is a simpler method to arrive at the correct answer.

What would be the probability of the third player surviving given that the second one survived?

@JP The third player survives and the second does not with probability $5/18$. The second and third players both survive with probability $13/18-5/18=8/18$. Divide by $13/18$ to get the answer of $8/13$.
